# Measuring the execution time of a function call in C using a function-like macro

Tags: c, macros, execution-time

Using the standard library function `clock()` is one of several methods to measure the execution time of a function call in C. So, for example, the comparison of the execution times of two functions (with different prototypes) can be done as follows:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>

int f(int n) { return n < 3 ? 1 : f(n-1) + f(n-2); }

int g(int n, int a, int b) { return n < 3 ? b : g(n-1, b, a+b); }

int main(void) {
    double start, elapsed1, elapsed2;
    printf("n  f   g\n");
    for(int n = 30; n <= 40; n++) {
        start = (double) clock();
        f(n); 
        elapsed1 = (clock() - start) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
        start = (double) clock();
        g(n, 1, 1);
        elapsed2 = ((double) clock() - start) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
        printf("%d %.1f %.1f\n", n, elapsed1, elapsed2);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

To make this code more concise, we could define a *function-like macro* (since there is no "generic function" pointer in C):

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>

double START, ELAPSED;

#define CPUTIME(FCALL) (START = (double) clock(), FCALL, ELAPSED = ((double) clock() - START) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC)

int f(int n) { return n < 3 ? 1 : f(n-1) + f(n-2); }

int g(int n, int a, int b) { return n < 3 ? b : g(n-1,b,a+b); }

int main(void) {
    printf("n  f   g\n");
    for(int n = 30; n <= 40; n++) 
        printf("%d %.1f %.1f\n", n, CPUTIME(f(n)), CPUTIME(g(n, 1, 1)) );
    return 0;
}
```

**Questions:** Is there a way to make variables START and ELAPSED local to the macro definition so that the macro can still be called as a non-void "function"? Is there a better way to make the code more concise, without using a macro definition?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the nonstandard *statement-expression* C extension
(available in at least clang, gcc, and tinycc).

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>

#define CPUTIME(FCALL) ({ double START = clock(); FCALL; ((double) clock() - START) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC; })

int f(int n) { return n < 3 ? 1 : f(n-1) + f(n-2); }

int g(int n, int a, int b) { return n < 3 ? b : g(n-1,b,a+b); }

int main(void) {
    printf("n  f   g\n");
    for(int n = 30; n <= 40; n++) 
        printf("%d %.1f %.1f\n", n, CPUTIME(f(n)), CPUTIME(g(n, 1, 1)) );
    return 0;
}
```

It's a parenthesized block that's evaluated to what the last statement in it evaluates to.

I don't think there's a generic solution within standard C that would satisfy your API constraints. If you're after standard-c-only threadsafety and/or slightly better codegen, you could use your original solution and (re)declare the variable(s) locally within the block that calls the macro.

Comment: I was actually hoping there was a solution using standard C. But if such a solution is not possible, I think the solution you propose is acceptable. Thanks for the answer!

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a better way to make the code more concise, without using a macro definition?

While the macro definition is clever, just a plain function can reduce the repetition and is simple to understand:

```
double seconds_since(clock_t start)
{
    return (double)(clock() - start) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
}

int main(void) {
    clock_t start;
    double elapsed1, elapsed2;
    printf("n  f   g\n");
    for(int n = 30; n <= 40; n++) {
        start = clock();
        f(n); 
        elapsed1 = seconds_since(start);

        start = clock();
        g(n, 1, 1);
        elapsed2 = seconds_since(start);

        printf("%d %.1f %.1f\n", n, elapsed1, elapsed2);
    }
    return 0;
}
```